# Converting these Networking Command Lines to /etc/network/interfaces file?

Tags: linux, networking

I am currently working with a LIDAR that requires one to run several commands:

https://data.ouster.io/downloads/software-user-guide-v1.13.0.pdf

The commands are listed here:

```
ip addr flush enp2s0f2
ip addr show dev enp2s0f2
sudo ip addr add 10.5.5.1/24 dev enp2s0f2
sudo ip link set enp2s0f2 up
ip addr show dev enp2s0f2
sudo dnsmasq -C /dev/null -kd -F 10.5.5.50,10.5.5.100 -i enp2s0f2 --bind-dynamic
```

The documentation says:

> See the documentation for your operating system on how to make these changes persistent, e.g., by using a network configuration daemon like NetworkManager

Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this. I know we need to add some lines to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. Can someone tell me how to do this? I'm effectively assigning a static IP-address at bootup, and then running a local DHCP server for that port

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to `/etc/network/interfaces` should work:

```
allow-hotplug enp2s0f2
iface enp2s0f2 inet static
address 10.5.5.1/24
post-up dnsmasq -C /dev/null -F 10.5.5.50,10.5.5.100 -i enp2s0f2 --bind-dynamic
pre-down killall dnsmasq
```

- dnsmasq should be spawned in background (don't use `-kd` options) as otherwise `ifup` would hang.
- dnsmasq is killed before the interface goes down.

Comment: This isn't working for 20.04 anymore

Comment: Note that Ubuntu by default uses `systemd-networkd` (or even `NetworkManager`?) for a while, which does not use `/etc/network/interfaces` but it's own configuration files in `/etc/systemd/network/*.link`. Since the question was about how to convert your manual commands into `/etc/network/interfaces` settings, I assume it is effectively used. `ifupdown` is the package which ships the `networking.service` which sets up network interfaces based on `/etc/network/interfaces`. Check `systemctl status networking` if it is running.